# Java Netbeans Mssql

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

[image]

> [#|2017-03-16T11:11:28.612+0200|SEVERE|glassfish
>   4.1|com.mrkcn.servlet.LoginServ
>       let|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(2);_TimeMillis=1489655488612;_Level
>       Value=1000;|
>         com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P2'.
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError
>       (SQLServerException.java:216)
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServ
>       erStatement.java:1515)
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePrep
>       aredStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecC
>       md.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLSe
>       rverConnection.java:1715)
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLSer
>       verStatement.java:180)
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLS
>       erverStatement.java:155)
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(
>       SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
>               at com.mrkcn.servlet.KonularServlet.doGet(KonularServlet.java:53)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java
>       :1682)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
>       alve.java:318)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
>       alve.java:160)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.j
>       ava:734)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.jav
>       a:673)
>               at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
>       ava:174)
>               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.j
>       ava:416)
>               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
>       a:283)
>               at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallab
>       le.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>               at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(Container
>       Mapper.java:167)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.
>       java:206)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.ja
>       va:180)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpSer
>       verFilter.java:235)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(Executor
>       Resolver.java:119)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(De
>       faultFilterChain.java:283)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart
>       (DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultF
>       ilterChain.java:132)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultF
>       ilterChain.java:111)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.jav
>       a:77)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNI
>       OTransport.java:536)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(Abstr
>       actIOStrategy.java:112)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerTh
>       readIOStrategy.java:117)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(Wo
>       rkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadR
>       unnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(Abs
>       tractThreadPool.java:591)
>               at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(Abstra
>       ctThreadPool.java:571)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       |#]

I am using java netbeans web service. Mssql gives error during den select command. What can be the problem ?

There is no trouble in another question. Did I put the question marks at the wrong place? No problem with sql as seen from sql management

```
String uye = req.getParameter("uye");
                JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
                ArrayList<String> konularList = new ArrayList<String>(100);
                ConnectInfo connect = new ConnectInfo();
                Connection con;
                PreparedStatement pstmt;
                ResultSet rs;
                PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                con=connect.baglanti();
                String Sorgu = "select t.id,t.uye,t.baslik,t.mesaj,t.kategori,format(t.tarih, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm') as tarih,t.edittarih,t.aktif,t.indirimpuani,t.altkategori,t.link, isnull((select case when t.id = f.konuid and f.uye = ? then '1' else '0' end from takipkonu f where t.id = f.konuid and f.uye = ?),'0') as takip from konular t ?";
                pstmt=con.prepareStatement(Sorgu);
                pstmt.setString(1,uye);
                pstmt.setString(2,uye);
                pstmt.setString(3,"order by t.tarih");
                rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    j.put("id", rs.getInt("id"));
                    j.put("uye",rs.getString("uye"));
                    j.put("baslik", rs.getString("baslik"));
                    j.put("mesaj", rs.getString("mesaj"));
                    j.put("kategori", rs.getString("kategori"));
                    j.put("altkategori", rs.getString("altkategori"));
                    j.put("tarih", rs.getString("tarih"));
                    j.put("edittarih", rs.getString("edittarih"));
                    j.put("aktif", rs.getInt("aktif"));
                    j.put("indirimpuani", rs.getInt("indirimpuani"));
                    j.put("link", rs.getString("link"));
                    j.put("takip", rs.getString("takip"));

                    konularList.add(j.toString());
                }
```

Comment: Add stacktrace as text not as image

Comment: I added -------